# How can I pass a list from a form in JS as JSON to the backend?

Tags: javascript, java, json

This is my list that I want to send to backend to create `Car` objects (This class is also shown below).

```
<form id="newBrand">
        <fieldset>
            <ul id="formCars">
              <li>
                <legend>Car 1</legend>
                <label>Name
                    <input type="text" name="carName1" />
                </label>
              </li>
              <li>
                <legend>Car 2</legend>
                <label>Name
                    <input type="text" name="carName2" />
                </label>
              </li>
            </ul>
        </fieldset>
    <button type="submit">ADD</button>
</form>
```

This is `Car` class:

```
public class Car {
private String name;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

}
```

I need to send my list from the form as JSON and assign the items of my list to the `cars` property inside that JSON because my sent JSON from JS will be deserialized to this class:

```
public class Foo {
private Set<Car> cars;

public Set<Car> getCars() {
    return cars;
}

public void setCars(Set<Car> cars) {
    this.cars = cars;
}
}
// JS code: 
const form = document.getElementById('newBrand');

form.addEventListener('submit', async (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();

            fetch(`/brands`, {
                method: 'post',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    'Accept': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    cars: [
                          // here I need to insert my list items from the form
                    ]
               })
            })
        });
```

I will also mention that I just want to get all the items from my list, regardless of their quantity. In other words i want my code to work no matter how many cars (there are currently two cars) I want to send to the backend.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Now it works as expected:

```
body: JSON.stringify({
     cars: getFormCars()
})
function getFormCars() {
            let result = [];
            const cars = formCars.querySelectorAll('li');
            cars.forEach(car => {
                var input = car.querySelector('input');
                result.push({
                    name: input.value
                })
            })
            return result;
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to read again the reference:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form.

See the `method` (the HTTP method) and `action` (backend URL) HTML attributes

Comment: I know about that but i don't know how it would help me to send data from the list in the form to allow them to deserialize to a set